# Why does $\tan^{-1}{x} \neq \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$ when $x=0.353553$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $$\tan^{-1}{x} \neq \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$$ when $x=0.353553$?

Inputing the value in the calculator gives 0.339837 and 2.70959 for the left and right side, respectively. I’ve spent an hour on the problem but I couldn’t figure it out. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: $tan^{-1}x$ is probably the arc tangent and not the cotangent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the two exponents $^2$ and $^{-1}$ conventionally have entirely different meanings when applied to trigonometric functions.

The $^2$ usually refers to standard multiplication, as in $$\tan^2x=(\tan x)\cdot(\tan x)$$On the other hand, the $^{-1}$ refers to function composition, like this:
$$
\tan^{-1}(\tan x)=x
$$
(for suitable $x$). Composition of functions behaves "product"-like in certain respects, and therefore often borrows product-related notation.

While we do have
$$
\frac1{\tan x}=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}
$$
(for suitable $x$), this is not what $\tan^{-1} x$ usually refers to.

Comment: Assuming you (OP) are in an Algebra II/Trig course or something like that, this is something that the instructor should take a few minutes on when first introducing inverse trig functions.